# What happens to a Process in a using statement without WaitForExit()?

Tags: c#, process, idisposable, using

In the following example, what happens to the process if it is still running once the code leaves the using statement?

```
using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\temp\\SomeConsoleApp.exe";
    p.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One should separate the OS process that is running on your system from the `Process` object that *represents* a "handle" to it in your program:

- The process continues running until it completes, or you kill it using OS-specific methods
- The `Process` object gets disposed, so your program can no longer interact with the OS process.

Call of `Dispose()` method on the `Process` object does not kill the OS process.

Comment: > "kill it using OS-specific methods"
How to know, is the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()`, for example, OS-specific? I don't see anything about this at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-5.0)
Or the fact, I don't see it, is the sign, says: "it isn't OS-specific"?

Comment: @user1234567 I mean things like `kill <pid>` on UNIX, or `taskkill /F /PID <pid>` on Windows, not C# methods.

Answer (score 1):

As you might know `using` statement will call `Dispose` method, so the process instance will be Disposed.

To interact with the process, to get the process related information you need [`Handle` to the Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). .Net framework internally holds the Handle to the process and takes all the pain for you. Dispose will close the process `Handle` and thus you'll not be able to make use of `Process` object in a good way anymore.

And most important thing: Nothing happens to the process which you started, it runs as if nothing happens. Really nothing happened, *you just lost the key to the door, doesn't mean that room is destroyed.*

Answer (score 0):

Process will be running util you close it. It will not die just because process' object scope ends.

Comment: Scope has nothing to do with this question

Comment: @SriramSakthivel OP has used `using`, so he is expecting process to die if object goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes, he used `using` how that's related to scope?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Once he goes out of `using` block, p will die. So he is expecting spawned process should also die.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `p` will die. What do you mean by die? All what happens is `Dispose` is called on a process instance, and that's it. Your answer is correct indeed, but that scope part is what little confusing for me.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I mean to say p will not be used out of using block. That means it will get Garbage Collected. Am I wrong?

Comment: Assume that `p` is defined somewhere out of the using block and stored as a field in a class. Then, if op used `using(this.p){...}` then `p` will not go out of scope or Garbage Collected either. It will just be Disposed. Main question here is what happens when the process is disposed, not what happens when the process goes out of scope. I think that makes sense.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes I got it now. Please give me sometime, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Process will continue running.You can move the Process p to a class member and stop the process in the OnStop to make sure that you can stop the service again if the exe goes haywire.

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    p.Kill();
}
```